# Why didn't the Demogorgon bring Jonathan to the Upside Down?

Tags: plot-explanation, stranger-things

In the first season of *Stranger Things*, Nancy and Jonathan attract the Demogorgon with blood to kill it.

When it comes, it attacks Jonathan trying to bite him.

Why doesn't the Demogorgon bring Jonathan directly to the Upside Down like it did with Barb and Will?

Comment: (...) like it did with Barb and Will? Did it, really? We quite purposefully *don't* know how exactly they got into Upside Down. It's actually more likely that they got through these temporary weak points on their own, perhaps to run away from the monster, but it got them only *after* they were already there.